# Two separate Django apps require the same models

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say my Django projects has two apps: `App A` and `app B`. Both apps require using 10 models.

Is it common practice to create another App just for the models and have it imported by `App A` and `app B`?

I know I can define them in either `App A` and `app B` and have the one without them import them from the other app, but for some reason I'm bothered by it. It seems more logical to me that both apps should import a "required models" app, than models from one another.

I'm new to Django, what's the common practice in such case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you can create an app named `utils` where you should place any common models, serializer, method, etc.

If you need commons models, create them in `utils/models.py`

If you need commons functions, create a Mixin Class implementing thoses method in `utils/mixins.py`

We call `Mixin Class`, a python class where you put any kind of method in order to re-use it on your views/models/serializer.

Also, it's a good practice to define models in a common app, because you can avoid circular dependencies, if you define a `modelX` in your `app A`, then you import it on your `app B`, if for some reason, `app A` would need some model from `app B`, you will get a circular import error.

**Example about mixin**

We have a normal view

```
class MyView(View):
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    .....
```

Let's say that we want to allow only logged user get it.  We just need import login required mixin and add it

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

That logic to check if the user is logged or not, is done in LoginRequiredMixin class.

This applies too for models, serializers, etc.